# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes (but I'm not using a string) -- Python 3

Tags: python, string, byte, pytest

I have a function that attempts to concatenate a few byte strings:

data.py

```
def hash_object (data, type_='blob', write=True):
    """ Returns a sha1 hash given bytes data
    :param data: the contents of a file
    :type data: bytes
    :param type_: type of git object
    :type _type: string
    :return oid: a sha1 hash
    :rtype oid: string
    """
    obj = type_.encode() + b"\x00" + data # error raised here
    oid = hashlib.sha1(obj).hexdigest()
    if write == True:
        with open (f'{GIT_DIR}/objects/{oid}', 'wb') as out:
            out.write(obj)
    return oid
```

The `data` parameter is take from this function in another file meant to handle the cli:

cli.py

```
def hash_object (args):
    """ hashes a file supplied through args param
    :param args:
    :type args: parser.ArgumentParser
    """
    with open (args.file, 'rb') as f:   # notice this is opening as bytes and feeding it to data module
        print (data.hash_object (f.read ()))
```

The error is pointing to this line:

```
obj = type_.encode() + b"\x00" + data
```

When I check the types of each argument of `+`, I can confirm they are `bytes`.  But the error message I get says the following:

```
>       obj = type_.encode() + b"\x00" + data
E       TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Why does Python think this is str to bytes?

Comment: @TheMaster. I'm copying the code from (and adding tests to ) https://www.leshenko.net/p/ugit/#write-tree-ignore-ugit so the function names aren't mine.  But I don't find it that confusing - the `hash_object` func in `cli.py` delegates data to the 'backend' `hash_object` func in `data.py`.

Comment: @Stepan. `type_` is a string, should be `bytes`, so it's `encode()`:

`>>> a = 'ah'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(a.encode())
<class 'bytes'>`